Cloud Application Programming Model OData v2 proxy
I am running a cap backend application with express.js and want to access the odata services with v2. In this project I used the @sap/cds-odata-v2-adapter-proxy which is now deprecated.
The recommended package is now @sap-js-community/odata-v2-adapter.
I tried to implement the proxy in the same way as the deprecated proxy. It did not work and I did not get any error messages.
This is my server.js
const express = require('express');
const proxy = require('@sap-js-community/odata-v2-adapter');
const cds = require('@sap/cds');
const app = express();

app.use(proxy());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

(async () => {
  await cds.serve('TestService').in(app).at('/test');

  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4004);
})(); 


Hi! Could you please share the output you see on the console after launching the application (cds watch)? Also, once launched, what happens when you load the application into the browser on the default (4004) port? Could you try to load the Welcome to @sap/cds Server page provided by cds serve? Also, could you please share what version of npm packages are installed in your project directory? Either by including package.json or the output of npm ls from the project root.
